# MySQL - Select results with specified ID or with null

Tags: mysql

I have one table:

```
| ID | ADV_ID | USER_ID |
| 1  |   22   |   NULL  |
| 2  |   22   |    3    |
| 5  |   44   |   NULL  |
```

and now, I want to select row where `adv_id = 22` and `user_id = 3`. If that row doesn't exist, I want to get row where `adv_id = 22` and `user_id is null`.

I tried in that way:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE adv_id = 22 AND (user_id = 3 OR user_id is null)
```

but this query return two rows - with `user_id = NULL` and with `user_id = 3`. I want to get one row - with `user_id = 3` or (if not exist), with `user_id = NULL`.

How I can do it in one query?
Thanks.

Comment: You can sort by `user_id` and limit 1.

Comment: it doesn't help me. This is table with images, so one advert can has 5 images, other advert can has 15 images, so I can't calculate LIMIT value.

Comment: USER_ID = NULL - this is default image. USER_ID = X - this is image which was uploaded by user. When USER_ID = X doesn't exist, I want to select default images (USER_ID = NULL). But how I can do it in one query?

Comment: IMHO the first comment is the right direction to answer this question. If it doesn't help you, then your question is not complete. `order by USER_ID is null limit 1` works for your sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ADV_ID,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN USER_ID = 3 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 3 END USER_ID
    FROM yourTable
) t2
    ON t1.ADV_ID = t2.ADV_ID AND
       ((t1.USER_ID IS NULL AND t2.USER_ID IS NULL) OR (t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID))
WHERE
    t1.ADV_ID = 22;
```

### Demo

For an explanation, the subquery I have aliased as `t2` aggregates over the `ADV_ID`, and outputs the value `3` if that value occurs in one or more records, otherwise it outputs `NULL`.  Then, we join this subquery back to your original table on the condition that both `USER_ID` values are `NULL`, or, if not, that the two `USER_ID` values match.

You may modify the demo to see that it generates the output you want for other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE ADV_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE USER_ID IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM test 
    WHERE ADV_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID IS NOT NULL
)
```

Select all rows with the first condition: `ADV_ID IS NOT NULL AND USER_ID IS NOT NULL`

and then `UNION ALL` with the same table if the first condition is `NOT EXISTS`.

So we only get results if the first condition is not returned any rows.

The MySQL **UNION ALL** operator is used to combine the result sets of 2 or more SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

try like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` t1 WHERE (t1.adv_id = 44) 
AND ((t1.user_id = 3)  OR 
     (NOT EXISTS (select * from `table` t2 where t2.adv_id=t1.adv_id and t2.user_id = 3) AND t1.user_id is null ))
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bYxw6JRLNhukStcfJo2i8V/0)